# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, shared-libraries

Getting error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already ran ldconfig and checked with ldconfig -v:

```
libboost_system.so.5 -> libboost_system.so.5
```

I used find to get the location of the library:

```
/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so.5
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.5
```

Here is part of the command:

```
-Wl,-gc-sections -L/usr/lib -lboost_system -Wl,--end-group
```

Honestly do not know what is causing the problem. Tried everything. Any help is necessary

Comment: what operating system? What architecture? Post your entire link line.

Comment: Ok i guess i solved it. The libs are actually in boost_1_55_0/stage/lib. So its -L/root/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib and i had to add that directory to /etc/ld.conf.d/libs.conf and ran ldconfig with it.

Comment: @JohnSmith Only if you do not install boost. or Install it in a custom directory.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a comment. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> The libs are actually in `boost_1_55_0/stage/lib`. So its `-L/root/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib` and I had to add that directory to `/etc/ld.conf.d/libs.conf` and ran `ldconfig` with it.

@Drax noted:

> Only if you do not install boost. or Install it in a custom directory